# Box-shadow в Firefox светлее чем в Сhrome

Tags: google-chrome, html, firefox, css

http://jsfiddle.net/xqnkU/

```css
.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 200px black;
  width: 157px;
  height: 113px;
  border-radius: 130px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow"></div>
```

Как сделать чтобы одинаково рендерилась тень, такое никуда не годится.

Answer (score 1):

Решил с помощью указания media-query для ff

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 .box:hover {
  box-shadow(0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0px 4px 2px -2px rgba(255,255,255,0.7),     inset 0px -3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0px -20px 130px -120px rgba(0,0,0,0.9));
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

А **-moz-box-shadow** не работает?